# Pulling Hyperparameters from a Pipeline Object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm using LogisticRegressionCV on my data in a pipeline. After fitting to the data, I'd like to return my optimal C value. How do I do this since I can't use .best_params_ since that is a feature of GridSearchCV. I know that .C_ is the correct feature of LogisticRegressionCV, but my estimator is in a pipeline, so that doesn't work right now.

```
lr_cv2 = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                 ('classifier', LogisticRegressionCV(solver='liblinear', cv=10, Cs=np.logspace(-5, 8, 15) ))])
lr_cv2.fit(X_train, y_train)
lr_cv2.C_
```

AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'C_'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `named_steps` method of your instance of `Pipeline`, you can access to the methods composing the single elements of your pipeline:

```
print(lr_cv2.named_steps['classifier'].C_ )
```